# Rails 4: Order by has_one value with alternate name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_one :baz, -> class_name: 'Bar'
end

class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @foos = Foo.includes(:baz).order ...?
  end
end
```

I would like to order my index of `Foo` based on `Baz.value`. However, I'm unable to find a command that works. rails console ...
`Foo.includes(:baz).order('baz.value')` generates an error. What can I do here?

Comment: On what model you have the foreign key? I presume on "Baz" there is a foo_id, right?

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis In Foo, `:baz, -> foreign_key: :foo_name, primary_key: :name`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `baz` table actually. You have the `bars` table, because of `class_name: 'Bar'`.

So the correct will be `Foo.includes(:baz).order('bars.value')`

Comment: I figured this out the other day and thought I had found my solution, but I still think I'm missing something. To add a little complexity, when sorting by `bars.value` I still want to sort by `Foo.name`, however only 3 `Foo's` show up when I `Foo.includes(:baz).order('bar.value asc, name asc')`

Comment: Ok, you do it correct if `bar` doesn't contain `name` column. If it is then you need `order('bar.value asc, foo.name asc')`. What's the question?

Comment: Bar has a `foo_name` column, but for the heck of it I changed it to `order('bars.value asc, foos.name asc')` and only 3 of my 30 test values appear. All of them have a baz, and they all show up without `foo.name`, but with it all but 3 disappear.

Comment: Look, the `Foo.includes(:baz).order('bars.value asc, foos.name asc')` generate `select` with `left outer join`. Just look to the log and try to run this query on database. You'll find the problem with the data.

Comment: I've run the command in rails console, which returns an activerecord object of all values. I've looked at the Rails server logs, and then compared the SQL between both. The SQL is exactly the same, minus the pagination (bootstrap-will_paginate gem). I removed the pagination, and all values show up (albeit not correctly). Any ideas, these bugs are getting a little obscure!

Comment: After playing around a bit, I have some more info to add. With paginate on (grabbing 30 recs) I'm able to see the first 3 records. Going to the second page allows me to view the next 3. To summarize, the first 6 records are visible over 2 pages even though it should be showing me 30 at a time.

Comment: So. You can see all 30 record on 10 pages by 3 records per page, right? Then just set `self.per_page = 30` in the model.

Comment: Negative. I have 50 records and 2 pages, only 6 records are visible at 3 per page.